# I'm having trouble installing rapids.ai on my windows 10 desktop

Tags: rapids, cudf

I have installed WSL2. I have tried both the pip installation and conda installation.

i'm getting a package not found error:  rapids=23.10*

I'm completely lost and am hoping someone will guide me through the process

Answer (score 2):

More specifics (the command you ran, where you ran it, system information like Python version [RAPIDS supports `3.9` and `3.10`]) would be useful in fully helping you debug your issue, but some general info:

1. https://docs.rapids.ai/install has a pretty comprehensive guide on how to install.
2. Specifically check out the WSL2 section - it's important if you're going to use pip vs Docker or conda. With pip you must install the Ubuntu-WSL CTK into your WSL Ubuntu installation, with conda/Docker you do not need to do that.

A couple other WSL recommendations:

1. Ensure you did *not* install a driver inside your WSL ubuntu installation. This will cause errors; WSL2 uses your Windows driver
2. Ensure you're on WSL2 specifically - WSL1 is not supported. To check, in an admin powershell run the command `wsl --list --verbose` and ensure you see "VERSION" `2` for your WSL installation

Comment: Also, while you *can possibly* get something working, Windows 10 is not a supported OS for RAPIDS WSL2 installs.  By upgrading to 11, you'll unlock full support and some cool, upcoming dev capabilities.